# Using Rule Flow in InRule for Workflow

Tags: rules, rule-engine, inrule

I see Rule Flow which supports action so it may be possible to build some types of workflow on top of this. In my situation I have an case management application with tasks for different roles, all working on a "document" that flows through different states and depending on state, different role will see in their queue to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your question is, but [InRule comes with direct support for Windows Workflow Foundation](http://www.inrule.com/products/integrations/windows-workflow-foundation/), so executing any InRule RuleApplication, including those with RuleFlow definitions, is certainly possible.

If you'd like assistance setting up this integration, I would suggest utilizing the support knowledge base and forums at http://support.inrule.com

Full disclosure: I am an InRule Technology employee.

Answer (score 0):

For case management scenarios, you can use decisions specifically to model a process.  Create a custom table or flags in your cases that depict the transition points in your process (steps).  As you transition steps, call a decision which will determine if the data state is good enough to make the transition.  If it is, then set the flag for the new state.  Some folks allow for multiple states at the same time.  InRule is a stateless platform; however, when used with CRM it provides 95% of the process logic and relies on CRM to do the persistence.  I have written about this pattern in a white paper:

https://info.inrule.com/rs/inruletechnology/images/White_Paper_InRule_Salesforce_Integration.pdf